# jquery doesn't find <a> within <ul>

Tags: jquery, selector

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="alumni_articles" class="slide-category" style="display:none">
    <ul id="alumni_articles_mode_switch" class="mode_switch">
        <li><a href="#" class="active show_slide_view">Slide View</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="#" class="show_list_view">List View</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="alumni_slide_content">
        .
        .
        .
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use this jQuery code to remove the `active` class from the opposite link and add it to the one that's just been clicked:

```
function showAlternateView(view)
{
    $("#alumni_articles_mode_switch li a").removeClass("active");
    $("#alumni_articles_mode_switch li a.show_"+view).addClass("active");
}
```

The function is passed either `"list_view"` or `"slide_view"` when "List View" and "Slide View" are clicked, respectively.

The function is called correctly, and the correct parameter is passed.  The problem is that jQuery is returning an empty set of objects to remove the class from or add it to.

(There are "faculty" and "student" variations in addition to "alumni" and I'm trying to build a generic solution rather than putting IDs directly on the `<a>` elements.)

I've tried a *lot* of variations on the selector and IDs, and can't get it to work.

What am I missing?

Comment: How is the function being called? And can you post a ([minimal/sscce](http://sscce.org/)) [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Your selector seems to work to me...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vdBUM/ it works here... are you certain you don't have a spelling mistake in either the `alumni_articles_mode_switch` or on `show_clide_view` or `show_list_view`?

Comment: is the `alumni_articles_mode_switch` id unique in your document ?

Comment: I can't find any problems here

Comment: Incidentally, how does a user click on those links, given that the parent element has `display: none` in its `style` attribute?

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
var $ul = $('#alumni_articles_mode_switch');

$ul.on('click','a',function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
        $ul.find('a').toggleClass('active');
    }
});
```

This should toggle classes between them, as long as there is only two and one starts as `active`. The if logic is just to prevent toggling when links that are already active are clicked.

[jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rv4Ta/3/).